# How to check if generic class is istanceof Number?

Tags: java

It may sounds simple but how to check if generic `T` class in java is "instanceof" `Number` class without having an object? I need something like `if (T instanceof Number){}` but it does not compile.

And my second problem: How to check if an generic `T` class implements other class?

Comment: Please take the time to do some [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and share what you've found and why it doesn't help you, then make an [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and post enough [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) to provide a [MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) per the help article [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was trying to find answer for my problem but I was usually finding tutorials how to do it with existing initialized object instead of class.

Comment: If you only want `T` to be able to be an instance of `Number`, you could declare it as `<T extends Number>`

Comment: I just want to check if generic `T` is an `Number` without having object. With object it is very easy - object.class.instanceOf(Number). But without it, it is not.

Comment: @Albert451 What are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to include a sample code of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to do, because at Runtime there is not Generic type. Only `Object`.